# Display error message on HTTP error 500

Tags: php, http, get

I have a program that runs an HTTP GET request to the YouTube servers to retrieve a users playlist. If the user has entered their account name wrong a 500 error is thrown in the console and nothing loads on screen.

How can I catch the 500 error and display an error, say in an alert or something similar?

Comment: Depends on what you are using to retrieve this data. Are you using JavaScript?

Comment: sorry I didnt clarify, I am using PHP for the request

Comment: How are you using PHP when talking about console and alert? **Please show some code.**

Comment: Depending on your setup, maybe check for an error.log file in your http root..?

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error = something has gone wrong on the web site's server but the server could not be more specific on what the exact problem is. eg : may be of .htaccess missconfig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the problem is that you can't. The 500 error - if generated by your web server - tells you that something has gone wrong internally (such as a fatal error in a PHP file). You'll need to find out what is causing the server to return the 500 error and fix that.

Check the error logs of your web server to see what the actual error message is, and start there. You can also use the `error_log` statement in php.ini to log all PHP notices/warnings/errors to a specific file.